# Is there any research on the psychological impact of male children pushing same sex parent out of the bed?

Tags: pre-teen, research, bed-sharing

This question is about the impact on the psyche of a boy/tween who sleeps in their parents bed and as time goes on the father moves out of the bed.

Certain things that may be of importance are:

- Child replacing his father in the husbands role of sleeping in bed with his wife
- Child not having a good role model of being a husband
- Child having an over-inflated sense of entitlement
- Child having future issues with intimate relationships with opposite sex

Of course any other information that I can't predict is appropriate as part of the answer too.

This question is based off of [this](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/35827/i-need-advice-as-to-how-to-help-my-11-year-old-grandson-who-sleeps-with-his-mom) closed question.

**EDIT for elbrant**

I know a couple families where the kids have pushed the father out of the parents bedroom.  In the case of this question the why is neutral (not because the kid is scared or has special needs), it is just is.  The mother may have separate issues, but this question is focused on the young boy and the sociological and psychological impact of a father whose position is displaced and how that might impact a BOY and his expectations for future relationships and his own adult self image.  Also, this question has no interest in why the father allowed it to happen.  There is no expectation or consideration for something like alcoholism or depression in the father.  The families I know where this is happening have all appearances of normalcy and actively engaged in the community and work life.

Comment: I think I understand the question, but you need to clarify this statement: "Child replacing his father in the role of being a husband". It is correct if the only role of a husband is to sleep next to his wife every night, which isn't my definition of a husband's role. I think you will not get the answer you desire because the research isn't easily found.

Comment: We need more information to formulate worthwhile answer(s)... Is there a particular reason that a youth of this age would still be sleeeping in his Mother's bed? Is there a physical or pyschiatric issue involved in this? Also, what is the "real reason" that these parents no longer sleep in the same bed?

Comment: I don't think this is something that has been widely scientifically studied-- I wasn't able to find anything about cosleeping children that push the father out of bed, even without the age or gender constraint.  Overall, general articles and studies I can find seem about split between finding cosleeping beneficial, detrimental, or neutral for child's development!

Comment: @Meg that is an acceptable answer, you can feel free to add it as an answer.

Comment: @Meg - I searched high and low as well. Nothing. Too broad a set of conditions.

Comment: Are you talking about the father just deciding to go sleep somewhere else? I'd have a hard time believing a tween could displace their father from his own bed against his will. It sounds more like a "I need sleep and this place is too crowded for me" setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is something that has been widely scientifically studied-- I wasn't able to find anything about cosleeping children that push the father out of bed, even without the age or gender constraint. Overall, general articles and studies I can find seem about split between finding cosleeping beneficial, detrimental, or neutral for child's development!

Comment: I believe we underestimate the power and value of admitting and understanding that we don't know some things.